# Number of <DOC> tag in wt2g collection by unversity of Glasgow

Tags: machine-learning, information-retrieval

According to this website : http://ir.dcs.gla.ac.uk/test_collections/access_to_data.html , university of Glasgow distributes the wt2g collection for a cost. This collection is basically made up of several parsed web pages. I was curious how many  tags does the wt2g collection have. This will help me estimate the number of documents in the collection, which will further determine if I should buy the collection or not.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of documents in the WT2G corpus is 247491.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://trec.nist.gov/pubs/trec8/papers/acsys.pdf) article, there are 0.25 million pages in WT2g collection. But [this](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/jaa/IS4200.12S/projects/Project2PR.html) page's informations, implies that there are 0.18 million pages in that collection.